# Duply: Dropbox backend keeps complaining about missing env variables

Tags: mac-osx, environment-variables, duply

Good morning,
I'm using duplicity/duply to backup some of my linux machines. One of the targets is a Dropbox account and the backup basically works very well. Now, I'm trying to set up an option to restore the backup on my MacBook Pro (OS-X 10.11). 
I installed duply using brew and installed the dropbox module via pip. So basically, everything should be fine.

When calling duply the first time, it complained about the missing environment variables DPBX_APP_KEY and DPBX_APP_SECRET. So, I exported them temporarily (as they are only needed to create the OAuth-Token).

When I call 'env' on the terminal, the last two lines now say:

```
DPBX_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx
DPBX_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Even more, when I start python and execute:

```
import os
print os.environ
```

The variables also show up in the dictionary.

However, as you may expect, duply keeps complaining:

```
BackendException: dpbx: DPBX_APP_KEY environment variable not set
```

Does anybody here use duply in combination with a dropbox target under OSX? Or does anybody have any adiditional idea, what I can try here?

Maybe it's too simple so that I just can't see it :-)

Thanks in advance!
Norbert

Comment: are you sure that the env vars are exported? can you post the output of the 'export' command? ..ede/duply.net

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. Yes, I'm really sure that the vars have been exported. After hours of debugging and trying I ended up "downgrading" dupy and duplicity to the versions as installed by apt. This version seems to be more stable in this manner and works perfectly fine.